# Integral of a stochastic process and its differential

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let
$$
Z(t) = \int_0^tg(s)dB(s)
$$
where $g(s)$ is adapted. Ho do I prove that
$$
dZ(t) = g(t)dB(t)
$$
?

Comment: The second equation cannot be proved because $Z$ does not have differentiable paths. When you see such an equation always interpret it as a short form of the integral version (your first equation).

Comment: Thank you, it is clear!